# How to load OpenCV on Android?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to process images got from Gallery with OpenCV and display them on screen using functions like  `org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat`  or  `org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor`.
I initialised OpenCV library functions with  `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()`.

When I want to run the application, I get the following error message: `"Unfortunately * has stopped`".

Also I have the following log messages:

```
Trying to get library list
   Cannot load info library for OpenCV
   Library list: ""
   First attempt to load libs
   Trying to init OpenCV libs
   Trying to load library opencv_java
   Cannot load library "opencv_java"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: did you put the libopencv_java.so inside libs/armeabi ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load library statically,

```
if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
    Log.d("CVerror","OpenCV library Init failure");
}else{
    // load your library and do initializing stuffs like System.loadLibrary();
}
```

initDebug in your onCreate() method

Comment: Appreciate this answer, but as title of question you should add some more details for: `How to load OpenCV on Android?` as [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421494/5737774).